# What causes the difference of two SQL strings which look seemingly the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, join, special-characters

I have a join problem caused by special characters in a joining key. The key is nvarchar string. Both strings look confusingly the same.
(1) `Łódzkie`
(2) `Łódzkie`

The first is "normal". If I double click it the whole word is selected. If I double click the second word just the half of it is selected (`Ł` or `ódzkie`), depending which half is clicked.

I have tried to alter column type from nvarchar to varchar. 
I think the problem is caused by the first letter. I tried the ascii of the first letter of two cases as `select ASCII('Ł')` and in both cases I get the result 163.

No luck so far.

Comment: Sounds like you might have (hidden) system characters within the string.

Comment: You can write simple t-sql function to convert your string to array of unicode codes using function like `UNICODE`. So you will see difference.

Comment: Try casting the column as varbinary and inspect the code points: `SELECT CAST(Col1 AS varbinary(100)), CAST(Col2 AS varbinary(100))`.  Also, be sure to prefix Unicode literals with `N` in your analysis: `SELECT ASCII(N'Ł')`.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Yep, it solved the issue. The culprit was hidden not in the first letter but in the invisible second. It was invisible `CHAR(129)` - it looks kinda cuckoo egg of space without space. I found it with `unicode(substring(word,2,1))` Thank you all very much.